# F# - creating an array of tuples based on value and index of input array

Tags: f#

I have an array like so:

```
let array = [|"A";"B";"C";"D"|]
```

I want to create an array based on the original array's value and the index like this:

```
[|"A",0;"B",1;"C",2;"D",4|]
```

If there a way to do this without resorting to a loop?  I was thinking Seq.mapi or Seq.fold but I am not having much success with them....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function [Array.mapi](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340472.aspx) and [Array.collect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353905.aspx) should do the trick:

```
array |> Array.mapi (fun i e -> (i, e)) |> Array.collect (fun (a, b) -> [|string a;b|])
```

Evaluation of this expression yields:

```
val it : string [] = [|"0"; "A"; "1"; "B"; "2"; "C"; "3"; "D"|]
```

However, I have converted integer to the string. Otherwise compiler can't infer type of the array.

If you need to have an array with elements of different type you can use [Discriminated Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233226.aspx) type.
Here is an example:

```
type ArrayElement =
    | Int of int
    | String of string

[|"A";"B";"C";"D"|] |> Array.mapi (fun i e -> (i, e)) |> Array.collect (fun (a, b) -> [|Int(a);String(b)|])
```

Answer (score 1):

As Valera says, the answer lies in Array.mapi.

However I notice that your desired output isn't an array of differing types (strings and ints) as Valera suggests, but is an array of tuples of string*int.

In the light of this the answer is simpler:

```
let array = [|"A";"B";"C";"D"|]

array
|> Array.mapi (fun i s -> s, i)
```

(BTW I think your last index should be 3 not 4.)